# Controlling access to view in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to limit access to view by button only.
I mean I want to let user access the view only when he clicked the button (can't access if he just pasted url to view in address bar).
And not by ng-show with would just not show the view but by blocking it from loading.

Possible scenarios:

1. user is in users list view -> user is clicking 'Add user button' -> 'Add user' view is loading - that's OK, that's how it should work
2. user is pasting address to 'Add user' view in address bar and trying to enter it - this try should be blocked, any other try besides by clicking button should be blocked.

Is there a way to do it?
I'm using ui-router btw.

Comment: may you could set a datetime-value to the localStore or a cookie when the button is clicked and check the value on loading the new view?

Comment: or you could check the fromState in the $stateChangeSuccess event

Comment: Or you could just not put the functionality on a route in the first place -- if it's not something you want users to be able to access via url, why give it a url?  Have the "add user" button insert the add user component into the current view instead of rerouting.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ui-router, you can use the state without url. So, when user clicks the button 'Add user button' - you can just change the state, but not the url. In this case, nobody can access 'Add user' view by url.